# Is there a native(none-web) GUI client of pgadmin4?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4, native-client

I don't like web-based GUI, so I only installed the `pgadmin4-desktop` package for my Kubuntu 20.04, instead of `pgadmin4-web` and `pgadmin4`.

According to [the offical web page of pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/),

> A desktop runtime written in C++ with Qt allows it to run standalone
> for individual users...

I'm expecting that a native qt GUI app can be run, and acts as a pg-client, but I can NOT find it out anywhere, neither startting-menu nor the DESTDIR of the installation, i.e `/usr/pgadmin4/bin`.

There is only one program file `/usr/pgadmin4/bin/pgadmin4`, but running it still open a browser window to serve as a pg-client, instead of any NATIVE app!

Would anyone please tell me that:

Is the one so called "`A desktop runtime written in C++ with Qt`" meaning a native GUI client app? or only a management server that resides on the system tray?

If a native GUI client really exists, where to find it or how to start it?

Thanks a lot!

Pls forgive my ugly English.

Comment: I think that is simply a wrong statement on the homepage (maybe a left over from pgAdmin 3).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are you meaning that there is no native GUI client?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. But you'll probably need to ask that on the [pgAdmin mailing list](https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list/) to get a definite answer

Comment: @Leon , were you able to find a native GUI client for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this didn't exist when the question was asked, but there is now a "native" Pgadmin4 app. It's still Javascript, not Qt and C++, but it runs much smoother than the web-based one for me.

Instructions to install it for Ubuntu/Debian are at https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/, and reproduced here:

```
#
# Setup the repository
#

# Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously):
sudo curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add

# Create the repository configuration file:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'

#
# Install pgAdmin
#

# Install for both desktop and web modes:
sudo apt install pgadmin4

# Install for desktop mode only:
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop

# Install for web mode only: 
sudo apt install pgadmin4-web 

# Configure the webserver, if you installed pgadmin4-web:
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```